# Set Java command line property with bash globing

Tags: java, linux, bash

*Apologies if this is a duplicate (looked around but I can't seem to find an answer).*

Say you want to pass a command line property to a java program. E.g. `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-1.2.3.4/jre/lib/amd64`
Problem is that the `java-awesome` will get updated far too often so it would be a pain to keep that property up to date.

Assuming though that they'll always follow the name/version convention so you could probably get away with something like: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64` (i.e. using bash globing to expand to the correct path).

Question is would this work as a java property? 
`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
LIB_DIR=`find /usr/lib/jvm -name amd64 | grep 'java-awsome-' | tail -1`
java -Djava.library.path=$LIB_DIR .....
```

Comment: I cannot do that. I can only run an agent remotely (the VM is a jenkins node).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:
Create a symbolic link `/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-latest` which points to the latest version.
When launching your application, you can simply use `java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-latest/jre/lib/amd64`.

Comment: It actually works as written (`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64`) but it is not a very good solution. Unfortunately I don't have access to the system (I can only run an agent remotely there). Had I had access, creating a soft link would be the best way to go around.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work as written because what bash sees is `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64`, which is not a valid path name so does not get expanded.

Something like this will work:

```
-Djava.library.path=`echo /usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64`
```

But even this is very dangerous - what happens if the mask expands to more than one location?

I would suggest that you keep a link, and update that link very carefully each time you run or each time you install a new version of `java-awsome`.

Comment: Did you intend to include `java.library.path=` as part of the echo command (inside the backquotes)?

Answer (score 0):

It actually works as written (-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-awsome-*/jre/lib/amd64) but it is not a very good or safe solution.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the system (I can only run an agent remotely there). Had I had access, I think that creating a soft link, as per Robert Kock answer, would be the best way to go around.